# How to start two functions at the same time and only wait for the faster one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am having a working code, but not really sure that this is the right way. I have two functions, both making an API request that can take an arbitrary time between 1 and 5 seconds, but both are designed to return the same output. I want to run the two simultaneously and once the quicker finished its job, terminate the other and drop whatever it would return.

```
p1 = Process(target = search1, args=(name) )
p2 = Process(target = search2, args=(name) )

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    while p1.is_alive() and p2.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.2)

        if not p1.is_alive():
            p2.terminate()

        if not p2.is_alive():
            p1.terminate()
```

If I do not wait some time (0.2 seconds in this case) sometimes both are returning if both take somewhat the same time. I tested many times and it works, but is this the right way doing this? Is there any issue that can surface with this approach?

--- **ti7 suggestion**

Trying with threading after ti7's suggestion, now it works with threadings rather than Processes.

```
def search1(Q_result, name):
    result = somefunction()
    Q_result.put(result)

def search2(Q_result, name):
    time.sleep(10)
    result = somefunction()
    Q_result.put(result )


import Queue as queue
import threading

Q_result = queue.Queue()  # create a Queue to hold the result(s)

if __name__=='__main__':

    t1 = threading.Thread(
        target=search1,
        args=(Q_result, name),
    )
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
        

    t2 = threading.Thread(
        target=search2,
        args=(Q_result),
    )
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()


print(Q_result.get())
```

Comment: Do you have many of such tasks to do? Because for thousands of tasks to start and terminate processes takes quite a lot of time and resources. Also if it is just an API request then probably you can do same approach as you do but for lightweight Threads from `threading` module. But in general your approach is quite alright, one way of solving your task. But you solution is nice in a sense that it cleans all the resources, because when process is killed all resources are deallocated. But if you use threads then some resources may be leaked.

Comment: I have one more idea - if you have to do many tasks, many requests, and your next requests don't depend on results of previous ones then instead of doing 2-3 simultaneous same API requests you can do same time different requests, many in parallel. And only if some of these requests failed then only retry doing them second time. This technique will allow you not only to increase total performance, but also decrease unnecessary weight on API servers.

Comment: It is a search functionality of a mobile client so yes, these can even run 20-30 times concurrently at peak usage at the moment. Do you recommend using the threading module in this case?

Comment: Threading is just a way to increase performance. Because starting and killing processes takes quite a lot of time. If you need performance of cause threads will be faster. But threads have such drawback that when killed they don't cleanup resources, unlike Processes. Also threads by default can't be easily killed as processes. But to improve processes solution you can do next thing - instead of killing processes, for those that have already finished you can re-use them instead of killing and starting again, just send second task to same Processes, kill only if it is frozen.

Comment: Probably you're using Raspberry Pi or something old. Because `daemon = True` was introduced in Pyton 3.3 so you probably have python 3.2 or earlier. I see you have a tag Python 2.7.

Comment: I have python 2.7.12 - I know its old, but all my scripts are written in this, so changing to python3 is not an option here :(

Comment: Are you limited by the need to have only Python 2.7? It is not allowed by your task to upgrade to new Python 3.8? Because 2.7 is not even supported any more.

Comment: Changing scripts to Python 3 is not that difficult, just few syntax problems, like `print(x)` instead of `print x`.

Comment: BTW, there're automated tools that convert Py2->Py3 automatically. One is [Modernizer](https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) another one is [Futurize](http://python-future.org/futurize.html). The second one is a cool thing because it converts in a such way that afterwards same scripts are runnable by both Py2 and Py3. Also Futurizer just adds extra import in the beginning of script, imports that make your further code runnable by Py2 and Py3 same time, so your scripts are almost unmodified but upgraded. Ideal solution to my mind.

Comment: BTW, @ti7 just updated his answer to another solution for daemon, instead of `daemon = True` constructor argument you can use `t.daemon = True` on thread `t` instance, in Python 2.

Comment: I have also python3 installed, and could run this specific script with that version other than the rest. Then I saw @ti7 solution, and it works like charm. Thank you a lot for letting me know of these great tools, some time in the future I need to migrate to python 3, so those will certainly come handy!

Comment: Also as I understand this script that runs two API calls script is also run quite often using `python make_two_api_calls.py` command. This is also a place to be optimized if you want, because basically running python command is also creating and terminating a separate process which also quite slow. Probably you want to do this threads-creating logic right in the parent script. Ideally would be not to run any processes at all, just one main process which starts/kills many threads, then it will be maximum performant.

Comment: @Arty maybe you see the following question, what I am struggling with is to handle the situation if both threads fail with an exception so the main thread is blocked forever. Once I put the result in the queue it quits, but what if both the threads fail, the main thread hangs because there is nothing in the queue. Thanks a lot

Comment: There are two things that can be done. First thing that both threads put some special marker inside queue if they fail, e.g. `None` value. Then main thread will know that workers have finished but un-successfully. Another way is to fetch from queue non-blockingly, there is `q.get(block = False)`, which allows never to block queue, main thread with this function just checks if there is a result in the queue and if after some timeout (e.g. 15 sec) no result appeared then main thread should think that was failure and maybe re-do API calls. First way is probably easier and cleaner.

Comment: There is also second param to queue get (see [doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get)) - timeout, which allows to wait given amount of time, you just do `q.get(block = True, timeout = 15)`, which blocks main thread and waits for result, but thread will be unblocked in two cases - either if result is puted into queue before 15 seconds expired or `15` seconds is reached first then too function finishes (unblocks) and exception `queue.Empty` is raised which can be catched to figure out that there was no result after `15` seconds have passed.

Comment: Hi @Arty! Putting None in the queue as it is did cause returning to the main thread instantly without waiting if the other thread completes or fails. The timeout approach works, but brings in two problems: to make it as clear as possible, I added a new question here with my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412935/how-to-handle-failing-daemon-threads-and-continue-the-main-thread-without-specif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making *the same request* multiple times, you'll likely be better off just doing it once and contacting the owner of the service to improve its performance. (for example, it could be distributing connections and one of the nodes is very slow).

As **@Arty** notes, using [threads](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#thread-objects) will be lighter to create than a process, and so be more performant. You can make threads a daemon, so they don't need to be `.join()`ed to exit (blocking program exit until all of them are complete).

Async logic may be a little faster still, but can be frustrating to reason about, especially in Python 2. Additionally, you may find if you're using a 3rd-party library such as [Twisted's Defferred](https://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-20.3.0/core/howto/defer-intro.html), loading the needed libraries to be very slow and reduce performance overall.

With threads, you may find it convenient to get and put your results in a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html), which is both threadsafe and can [block until content is available](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get).

Rough thread example

```py
from __future__ import print_function  # print(x) over print x
import queue
import threading

# if these are the same logic, use an argument to differentiate
# otherwise you could have any number of unique functions,
# each of which makes some different request
def make_request(Q_result, request_args):
    result = "whatever logic is needed to make request A"
    Q_result.put(result)  # put the result into the Queue

list_of_different_request_args = []  # fill with whatever you need

Q_result = queue.Queue()  # create a Queue to hold the result(s)

# iterate over input args (could be list of target functions instead)
for request_args in list_of_different_request_args:
    t = threading.Thread(
        target=make_request,
        args=(Q_result, request_args),
    )
    t.daemon = True  # set via arg in Python 3
    t.start()

# get the first result, blocking until one is available
print(Q_result.get())

# program exits and discards threads
```

Comment: Hi! I edited my code based on your suggestion, take a look at the question now. The problem is that it doesnt accept daemon as a keyword in init. If I remove it, it runs but the slower thread blocks the exit. What might be the issue?

Comment: @AkosF Sorry! it's been a minute since I used Python 2; it's a property which should be set before starting the thread - I've updated my example! docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, now it works like charm!

Comment: Hi @ti7! Hope you see this question :) I am struggling to handle the situation if both threads fail with an exception so the main thread is blocked forever. Any idea how can I safely exit both threads in this case? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @AkosF please make a new question and link it here, tagging me again, but `Queue.get()` accepts a timeout argument, which will allow you to stop blocking and continue to exit (or whatever default value you like) docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get

Comment: Hi @ti7! The timeout approach works, but brings in two problems: to make it as clear as possible, I added a new question here with my code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412935/how-to-handle-failing-daemon-threads-and-continue-the-main-thread-without-specif