# How to handle failing daemon threads and continue the main thread without specifying a timeout value?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I have two simultaneously running functions as daemon threads, both putting their output to the queue and once the faster one completes, the main thread continues - the slower one either has value or fails, it doesn't matter. We do not know which one will be completed first, but my goal is to always return the main thread with the quicker one's result, which works well with the following code if no exception is raised in either thread. My problem is handling the case when both fail, in that case, I want to instantly return to the main thread.

```
def search1(Q_result, name):
    raise Exception("search1 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...")
    result = somefunction()
    Q_result.put(result)

def search2(Q_result, name):
    raise Exception("search2 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...")
    result = somefunction()
    Q_result.put(result )


import Queue as queue
import threading

Q_result = queue.Queue()  # create a Queue to hold the result(s)

if __name__=='__main__':

    t1 = threading.Thread(
        target=search1,
        args=(Q_result, name),
    )
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
        

    t2 = threading.Thread(
        target=search2,
        args=(Q_result),
    )
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()


try:
    res = Q_result.get(timeout=10)
    print res
except queue.Empty:
    print "Queue is empty, returning to main thread..."
```

The output after the timeout=10 seconds:

```
search1 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...
search2 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...
Queue is empty, returning to main thread...
```

There are two problems with this approach:

- what if both threads fail in way less time than the timeout, e.g. in 2 seconds - then I am waiting for 8 more seconds for returning to the main thread, rather than returning in 2 seconds
- what if one of the search thread takes more time than the timeout (I do not have much control over this to handle) and would return with a valid output, but timeout kills the thread before it would return it.

How to handle this? ([@ti7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4541045/ti7), [@Arty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941531/arty) any suggestion?)

Comment: You have to catch exceptions inside worker threads' functions, then if some function fails (has exception) you put None by this function into queue. Main thread gets first result from queue, if it is not None then program quits with successful first result. If first is None then main should wait for second thread. If second is not None then main returns result of second thread, if second is None too then it means both threads failed and main should do something about it like reporting error or redoing whole process.

Comment: Hi @Arty, if I put None into the queue in the except block in the worker thread's function, then it thinks it is a normal value to return and returns to the main thread - maybe it is valid only from python 3?

Comment: `None` is a valid value, you just need to check that queue result is not None like `if res is not None: print(res)`. Otherwise (`else`) you wait for second result.

Comment: [Here is full code](https://cutt.ly/7gjfSK5) that does what you need.

Comment: Thanks @Arty, it works perfectly! I was not thinking of the way checking the None as many times as many workers I have.. Could you please add an answer so I can except it?

Comment: Yes, sure I'll add my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch exceptions (try/catch) in both workers' functions and put some special value-marker like `None` or some string like `"__BAD_VALUE__"` into the queue.

Then main checks if first result in queue is not equal to this marker (`None`) then first good result is ready and main should print or return it to user. If first result in queue appeared to be bad (`None`) then main should wait for second result in queue. If second is not bad (not `None`) then it is returned to user, otherwise both workers failed and main should report total failure or somehow maybe redo whole process of two API calls.

Also timeout is still needed inside queue get function because any worker can hang for indefinite time for some reason without any exceptions and if both workers hanged then main should quit and report total failure again but for the reason of hanging workers (not excepting).

Full code down below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVOxjtswDN31Fex1sAwEbuMxgJcC17HAAbcLqk3HAmzJlWig6c@nlKU46SHopUs1ySL5@Pj4PJ9ocLY@n800O09AZkJh9YTQQKG/t4UQHfYQUPt22MsX5TEsI@0g5pQHAXzIn9IlHq9NQHj@2eJMxln5lEtToANtAS9BRnEE80Jk7JEjJ3AL8SeQAxoQfiy4YFVVT@UG/zH1Z3bBTdgvtl27XBO2eNEbHyjzLbb4ZYKK@8h0TcWJ1eF@4jdnsbyVon5AiqhlFUbEWe5vJ7ivUP3/FQrYOts9IhE8rpHITnqJ1ECHxPHySoNH3fEwQlyKmUkaY62QJY8ALWcRV2cUnnZwY7eOnIpk4FamB6Wi@ko1TaHUpI1VqjiItIs9I2/9qtf1Jq/b0f6I1GR77rZ3fg7N2@2mcJlxq07j5CzDv3oeLT8GRqQbnTOL@nEW9b@wqO@xqDcWQmxeZAxO2nbF/WS0JjuJn/efEx5rGfNMgLjHw61b3i/@G0A8szeWZPHF0QDRkQEG3V1dHj6h986HHS@a9Ai9NuPicQedW01MA0v3oXhLNP4af/ZKfThcigSenfU8zZTFyFS@5v@CiQTovfuFFnrnmYCD0dnju1TO598)

```
import time
name = 'abc'

def search1(Q_result, name):
    try:
        raise Exception("search1 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...")
        #result = somefunction()
        result = 'first_result'
        Q_result.put(result)
    except:
        Q_result.put(None)

def search2(Q_result, name):
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        #raise Exception("search2 raised an exception, not putting any output to the queue...")
        #result = somefunction()
        result = 'second_result'
        Q_result.put(result )
    except:
        Q_result.put(None)


import Queue as queue
import threading

Q_result = queue.Queue()  # create a Queue to hold the result(s)

if __name__=='__main__':

    t1 = threading.Thread(
        target=search1,
        args=(Q_result, name),
    )
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()
        

    t2 = threading.Thread(
        target=search2,
        args=(Q_result, name),
    )
    t2.daemon = True
    t2.start()


try:
    res = Q_result.get(timeout = 10)
    if res is None:
        res = Q_result.get(timeout = 10)
        if res is None:
            print('Both funcs had exceptions/errors, total failure, do something!')
    if res is not None:
        print(res)
except queue.Empty:
    print('Function has frozen for too long, total failure, do something!')
```